# Dropbox Api to get All images

Tags: reactjs, api, dropbox

Here is my Code in React.js, actually I want to get all the media files url from Dropbox Api. I am getting response from https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account and also from https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder but i don't know how to proceed furhter to get URL of all files.

```
handleSocialLoginDropbox(){
  axios({
    method:'post',
    url:'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account',
    responseType:'stream',
    headers: { Authorization : 'Bearer access_token'}
  })
    .then(function(response) {  
      console.log(response)
      axios({
        method:'POST',
        url:'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder',
        headers: { Authorization : 'Bearer access_token', 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        data : { path: "", include_media_info : true }
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response)

      });
  });
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're probably looking for the [/2/files/get_temporary_link endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link)? You can call that much the same way as /2/files/list_folder, by passing in the path, i.e., the `path_lower` for the file you want.

Comment: Thanks @Greg for you reply, can you please give me any coding example.?

Comment: I don't have a sample for this using `axios`. Please try writing the code you need and open a new post if it's not working as expected. It should work much the same way as the call to /2/files/list_folder.